# how do I reject random numbers in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I try to build a lottery number generator but I don't know how to make the random module to replay the number if was already generated or belong to an list.
So basically I want numbers from oldNumbers to not be generated again. Sorry if I'm not enough explicit but I leave the code here. thanks

```
import random

oldNumbers = [5, 11, 19, 20, 38]

ball1 = random.randint(1, 39)
ball2 = random.randint(1, 39)
ball3 = random.randint(1, 39)
ball4 = random.randint(1, 39)
ball5 = random.randint(1, 39)

print(ball1, ball2, ball3, ball4, ball5)
```

Comment: Ok, I deleted my answer because of @eyllanesc comment. In my defense, the question wasn't explicit in terms of desired or sample output.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple solution:

```
print(random.sample([i for i in range(1, 39) if i not in oldNumbers], 5))
```

or you can simply use `set` subtraction:

```
print(random.sample(set(range(1, 39)) - set(oldNumbers), 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two straighforward ways. The first one is two try random numbers multiple times and reject those that are in a list

```
import random
oldNumbers = [5, 11, 19, 20, 38]
for i in range(5):
    ball=random.randint(1, 39)
    while ball in oldNumbers:
        print('Rejected:',ball)
        ball = random.randint(1, 39)
    print(oldNumbers,ball)
    oldNumbers+=[ball]
```

The other way is to select random numbers only from a list that contains the numbers that you want.

```
import random
oldNumbers = [5, 11, 19, 20, 38]
for i in range(5):
    newNumbers = [i for i in range(1,39) if i not in oldNumbers]
    ball=random.choice(newNumbers)
    print(oldNumbers,ball)
    oldNumbers+=[ball]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Selcuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54120743/364696) is the best approach for your problem, but I thought I'd contribute an alternative that will be more efficient when the `range` is huge, and `oldNumbers` isn't too big.

```
from itertools import islice
from random import sample

forbidden = set(oldNumbers)

numneeded = 5

# Might have old numbers in it, but definitely has at least 5 new numbers
numbers = random.sample(range(1, 39), numneeded + len(forbidden))

# Generates only the new numbers
notForbidden = (num for num in numbers if num not in forbidden)

# Keep only as many as you need
newNumbers = list(islice(notForbidden, numneeded))
```

All of that (aside from imports) could be one-lined (`newNumbers = list(islice(filterfalse(set(forbidden).__contains__, random.sample(range(1, 39), 10)), 5))`) but I split it up for illustration.

This has the advantage of not needing to construct a filtered `list` to pass to `sample`, which if `range` got bigger, could become a problem for run time/memory. Instead, you just generate enough numbers that you're *sure* you've generated at least the amount you need, even if you happen to select all of the forbidden numbers, then keep only as many as needed.

Where Selcuk's answer is `O(n)` is the size of the `range`, this answer is `O(n)` in the number of numbers you need to generate plus the number to exclude (which should always be less than the size of the `range` for obvious reasons).

Comment: I think the point which @eyllanesc made on my answer (deleted now) also applies to your solution. Here the `notForbidden` should be used in a self consistent fashion. So all the 5 samples are not to be drawn simultaneously. That means if `[5, 11, 19, 20, 38]` is the starting oldNumbers, then the first random number can be one of these but then that particular number, let's say 11 cannot be generated again in the next four samples. It also means that it the first sample is not in the oldNumbers, let's say 10, then the second sample can again be 10 because it is not in the oldNumbers.

Comment: I am basically quoting here from OP "So basically I want numbers from oldNumbers to not be generated again. " which I translate as what I wrote in my first comment

Comment: @Bazingaa: That problem doesn't apply. I'm generating *10* *unique* values (even though only five final values are needed), then drawing the first five values that weren't in `oldNumbers`. Since I'm generating unique values, there must be at least five that aren't in `oldNumbers`, and they won't be repeated in `newNumbers` either (because again, all 10 are unique).

Comment: @Bazingaa: I could be wrong, but I interpreted "how to make the random module to replay the number if was already generated or belong to an list" to mean they didn't want to generate numbers from `oldNumbers` *or* numbers already generated in the production of the `newNumbers` (so if you generate 10 first, you shouldn't generate it for picks 2-5). After all, this is a lottery drawing, and by my understanding, there is only one ball with each number on it; if the last drawing's balls aren't put back in the bin, you can't generate them, and you can't generate any of the remaining numbers twice.

Comment: Simultaneously saying "how to make the random module to replay the number if was already generated or belong to an list." AND "So basically I want numbers from oldNumbers to not be generated again" is indeed confusing and doesn't go hand in hand. The latter means that the ball1, ball2, ball3, ball4 and ball5 can have same repeating number (excluding any of the ones in the oldNumbers) but the first quote says that all the five ball variables should be different and also excluding the oldNumbers. So yeah, as I said, the question wasn't clear.